# Sorting jqGrid by one value, when showing another value in the cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

A situation:

```
$("#CreditLineEditorContent #tabs #PmntDates").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ["Date", "In", "Out"],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'pmntDate', index: 'pmntDate', width: 150, sorttype: "date", sortable:false },
        { name: 'incSum', index: 'incSum', width: 150, sorttype: "float", formatter: 'currency' },
        { name: 'decSum', index: 'decSum', width: 150, sorttype: "float", formatter: 'currency' }
});
```

I need to sort my grid by column "**Date**".
The problem is following: I have a `pmntDate` as a **String** (e. g. *02.09.2013*), so it sorted as a `String`, not `Date`

*So, the question is*:
How can I show a `String` values (e. g. *02.09.2013*) but sort by original values (`Date`)?

Comment: @AshishNautiyal He wants to show `Date` as a `String` but sort as a `Date`

Comment: $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy'; use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot.
The right answer:

```
... sorttype: "date", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd.m.Y' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try datefmt option:

```
{ name: 'pmntDate', ..., sorttype: "date", sortable:true, datefmt: "dd.mm.yyyy" }
```

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options